# How Does This Grid App Template Scroll without a Scrollviewer? (C#/XAML Windows 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, scrollviewer

I've been trying to understand Scrollviewers, and thought I'd take a look at Microsoft's template for a Grid App for 8.1, whose content extends off the screen.  What's odd is that there doesn't seem to even *be* a Scrollviewer in the XAML page.  Can anyone tell me what is enabling the scrolling?

```
<Page
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="GridApp.GroupedItemsPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:GridApp"
xmlns:data="using:GridApp.Data"
xmlns:common="using:GridApp.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="ChevronGlyph">&#xE26B;</x:String>
    <!--
        Collection of grouped items displayed by this page, bound to a subset
        of the complete item list because items in groups cannot be virtualized
    -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Groups}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="Items"
        d:Source="{Binding Groups, Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid -->
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid GroupPadding="0,0,70,0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2">
                            <Button Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Click="Header_Click"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0,-11,10,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-11,0,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,40"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we go check out the default [GridView template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709916.aspx) and look for the `ItemsPresenter` we see it's embedded in a `ScrollViewer` at the template level. Since now we know there's one there, if we look up towards the top in the `Setter` declarations we've got some Properties available to us to interact with that `ScrollViewer` from the `GridView` itself by seeing;

```
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Enabled" />
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True" />
```

So if we wanted that `GridView` to not scroll anymore we could tell it not to like;

```
<GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```

since it's set to "Auto" at the template level by default.

That's the thing about templates, sometimes it just takes digging one level deeper. Hope this helps, cheers.